# how to set wrap indicator with image and text in tablayout in android

Tags: android

This is my xml i am display custom tab with image and textview in tab layout

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
                    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"                                   app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/menuRight"
                        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorTurquoiseBlue"
                        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp" />
                           <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/menuRight"
                        layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tabLayout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/blackDark"
                        android:padding="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
                        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tabLayout"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp" />   
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my customtab.xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
                    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"                                   app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/menuRight"
                        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorTurquoiseBlue"
                        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp" />
                           <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/menuRight"
                        layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tabLayout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/blackDark"
                        android:padding="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
                        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tabLayout"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp" />   
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cards_active" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvtab1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_cards"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTurquoiseBlue"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/attendessImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_attendees_active" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvtab2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/tab_attendees"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTurquoiseBlue"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

There are two first ll1 and second ll2 i one first tab selection
 i am visiblity hidning gone  second ll1 text  displaying selected tab text  same with  when we select second tab i am hiding first tab text which is in ll1 customtab.xml 
first tab text is CARD second tab text is ATTENDEES what happened 
in lower version device  tab indicator auto wrapped when we select tab according  text length and image  but in higher version 
 like 7 or 8 version its indicator  becomes equal  divided
 can please suggest me how to fix it . in given screen lower 
version device working fine below version 6 but in version 7 each tab indicator or width divided in to two equal part so my text 
becomes hide i have to make  it tab wrapped .